# Org-export scope subtree: ignore multiple trees with a single tag

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-tags

I use orgmode to export to latex using the subtree export command `C-c C-e C-s l l`.
Suppose I have a `.org` file like below:

```
* My main project
** Chapter 1 - Done
** Chapter 2 - Partially Done
** Chapter 3 - Todo
** Many other chapters that are still not complete
* My other project
* Many other projects
```

And I want to export the tree named `My main project`, including `Chapter 1`, but excluding all other chapters.

The easiest way to do this is to add the tag `noexport` to Chapter 2 onwards. However, if there are many Chapters, this can get tedious.

**Question:** Is it possible to create a tag, say `noexportonwards`, that when added to a subtree, like `Chapter 1`, will make org export ignore all subsequent trees?

Comment: Not an answer, but you can easily set/unset a tag on all the following subtrees by selecting a region from there until the end of file, and then `org-change-tag-in-region`.

Comment: ... or you can add a first-level heading after Chapter 1 and tag it as "noexport".